# Create a masking layer without direct image processing?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm basically trying to achieve this effect. It can be done with pretty much a PNG with a transparent hole cut through it, then stacked on top of a photo.jpg UIView. OR, I've also seen a method where you can directly create a mask with `CGImageMaskCreate`. I don't want to use that feature because I want the user to be able to interact with the photo.jpg layer (by moving it, rotating it, etc.):

[image]

Its essentially two UIViews stacked directly on top of each other.

However, what if rather than using blue, I wanted to use another color, or even pattern an image with `[UIColor colorPatternWithImage:]` for the masking layer? I wouldn't want to make a million different PNGs for each case.

Would I need some way to programmatically recreate my mask? Is there some way to convert my mask shapes into code? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CALayer` has a property called `mask`, which is another `CALayer` that defines the mask to use. You could use a `CAShapeLayer` to define the mask, then set that as the `mask` of another layer that renders your obscuring image/color/pattern/whatever. You could also use a regular `CALayer` as the mask with your semi-transparent image as the contents, it depends on whether or not you want the ability to customize the size/shape of the hole.

Caveats: `CAShapeLayer` is slower than normal layers, and `mask` is slower than non-masking as well. You may need to make sure performance is acceptable for you. You may also want to try out the `shouldRasterize` flag, though this will only improve performance (at the cost of memory) as long as the layer is static (i.e. not animating).